# How do I handle lazy loaded references when returning a model as JSON in Grails

Tags: json, grails, grails-orm

In Grails I have a model class User that has a one-to-one mapping with another model class Address.  When returning a user in JSON format from my controller I never see the address class, just the id.  In my User class I have:

```
class User {

    Address address

    ...

    static mapping = {
        ...
        address fetch: 'join'               
        ...
    }
```

And then in my controller I do

```
User user = user.get(1)
render user as JSON
```

Is there a way to change the mapping to make the 'as JSON' pull back the address class?

I am running on Grails 1.3.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting your converter to be deep?

JSON.use("deep"){
  User user = user.get(1)
  render user as JSON
}

There is a bit of stuff around the Custom Object Marshallers that you can dig into here, but my first try would be to just try the deep conversion.

Comment: Thanks tomas this seems to be what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

There are Two types of JSON Converters i.e:

```
grails.converters.deep.JSON
grails.converters.JSON
```

.
.
What you need is a Deep Converter,
Just change the Imported Class To:

```
    // Dont Use: import grails.converters.JSON
    import grails.converters.deep.JSON
```

**Note:** *Grails 1.3.7 import grails.converters.deep.JSON is fiine, in Grails 2.0 its deprecated.*

The Difference Between these two is, that the "Deep" one will also JSONify the nested Classes, Whereas Standard Converter will not.

Hope that help

Regards

Kushal